# Dash/ Plotly graph on mobile diasplaying width error

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am building a basic dashboard that displays the word count from messages in my friends' group chat.

The graph works correctly on a desktop browser:

[image]

However on mobile the graph has no width at all:

[image]

How can I fix this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing these meta_tags:

```
app = dash.Dash(
    meta_tags=[
        {"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}
    ]
)
```